# Calculate delta(difference of current and previous row) in sql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table like : 
trans is the name of the table for example

```
Id | Trans_Date          | Account_Id | Amount | Delta
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2011-02-20 00:00:00 |     2      | 1200   | NULL
------------------------------------------------------
2  | 2011-03-21 00:00:00 |     2      | 2000   | NULL
------------------------------------------------------
3  | 2011-04-22 00:00:00 |     2      | 4500   | NULL
------------------------------------------------------
4  | 2011-02-20 00:00:00 |     4      | 1000   | NULL
------------------------------------------------------
5  | 2011-03-21 00:00:00 |     4      | 2400   | NULL
------------------------------------------------------
6  | 2011-04-22 00:00:00 |     4      | 3000   | NULL
------------------------------------------------------
```

And I have to update Delta column. which value is the difference of current row of the same account and preceeding row of the same account assuming there is one transaction per month.
Here is a dummy sql which can generate the delta value

```
select tt1.id, tt1.amount , tt1.AccountId,(tt1.amount-tt2.amount) as delta 
from trans tt1 left outer  JOIN trans  tt2 
on tt1.accountid = tt2.accountid
where month(tt1.date1)-month(tt2.date1)=1 ;
```

The result of this query is

```
id | amount | AccountId  | delta  |
-------------------------------------
2  | 2000   |     2      | 800    | 
-------------------------------------
3  | 4500   |     2      | 2500   |
-------------------------------------
5  | 2400   |     4      | 1400   | 
-------------------------------------
6  | 3000   |     4      | 600    | 
-------------------------------------
```

But the delta of the row which has not any preceeding row should be its amount such as

```
1  | 1200   |     2      | 1200   | 
-----------------------------------------
4  | 1000   |     4      | 1000   | 
-----------------------------------------
```

these are missing by the way.

Please help me in resolving this query.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's your original query modified accordingly:

```
select
  tt1.id,
  tt1.amount,
  tt1.AccountId,
  (tt1.amount-ifnull(tt2.amount, 0)) as delta
from trans tt1
  left outer JOIN trans tt2 on tt1.accountid = tt2.accountid
    and month(tt1.date1)-month(tt2.date1)=1;
```

The month comparison is moved from `where` to `on`, which makes a difference for `left join`, and `tt2.amount` is replaced with `ifnull(tt2.amount, 0)`.

---

<s>The `UPDATE` version of the script:</s>

```
update tt1
set delta = (tt1.amount-ifnull(tt2.amount, 0))
from trans tt1
  left outer JOIN trans tt2 on tt1.accountid = tt2.accountid
    and month(tt1.date1)-month(tt2.date1)=1;
```

---

The correct MySQL syntax for the above update should actually be:

```
update trans tt1 
             left outer JOIN trans tt2 
             on tt1.accountid = tt2.accountid 
             and month(tt1.date1)-month(tt2.date1)=1 
set tt1.delta = (tt1.amount-ifnull(tt2.amount, 0));
```

(Thanks **@pinkb**.)

Comment: YEAH IT WORKS, THE RESULT OF THE QUERY IS EXACTLY WHAT WE WERE LOOKING FOR...THANX ANDRIY. USING THIS DELTA VALUE , HOW CAN I UPDATE THE SAME TABLE..ITS CONFUSING...QUERYING AS WELL AS UPDATING A TABLE AT ONE RUN. IN THIS CASE, THE DELTA HAS TO BE UPDATED.

Comment: Hey Andriy, Thanx a lot for your support. Actually after a little tweaking in your update script, everything works as we want. So here is tweaked version of your update scripts,                                                       update trans tt1 left outer JOIN trans tt2 on tt1.accountid = tt2.accountid and month(tt1.date1)-month(tt2.date1)=1 set tt1.delta = (tt1.amount-ifnull(tt2.amount, 0));

Comment: I see, I've got the syntax wrong. (MySQL isn't my 'native' SQL dialect.) Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner query, but it's not necessarily the most efficient query.

```
UPDATE trans
SET Delta = Amount - 
(SELECT Amount FROM trans t1
WHERE t1.Trans_Date < trans.Trans_Date
ORDER BY t1.Trans_Date DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Hey Tim thanx for your response. But unfortunately i am not able to execute your query successfully...mysql throws some exceptions.

Comment: It's because `TOP 1` isn't the part of MySQL. The equivalent is probably `LIMIT 1`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the MySQL bit. I've edited the above which *should* work for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Can you "union all" your query with a query that simply selects the first item for each account with the initial balance set as the delta, and the ID of that record as the id for the delta record?  The result would be ordered by ID.  Dirty but is it applicable?