# can we query by using the previous query output

Tags: mysql

In mysql can we query by using the previous output data .
ie.,

```
 select IPAddress,Sum(L2FramesSent),convert((min(datetime) div 500)*500, datetime) + INTERVAL 5 minute as endOfInterval from databasename.tablename  where datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-20 10:00:00' AND '2012-09-20 16:45:00' group by datetime div 500;
```

By the above query I got

```
+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+
| IPAddress | Sum(L2FramesSent) | endOfInterval       |
+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+
| moteid6   |            523791 | 2012-09-20 10:05:00 |
| moteid4   |            349555 | 2012-09-20 11:00:00 |
| moteid6   |            276358 | 2012-09-20 11:05:00 |
| moteid4   |            525457 | 2012-09-20 12:00:00 |
| moteid4   |            960010 | 2012-09-20 12:05:00 |
| moteid13  |           1263313 | 2012-09-20 12:10:00 |
| moteid12  |           1001343 | 2012-09-20 12:15:00 |
| moteid4   |            325904 | 2012-09-20 13:00:00 |
| moteid14  |            691390 | 2012-09-20 13:05:00 |
| moteid4   |           1028479 | 2012-09-20 15:40:00 |
| moteid12  |           1394286 | 2012-09-20 15:45:00 |
| moteid12  |           1336231 | 2012-09-20 15:50:00 |
| moteid6   |            263674 | 2012-09-20 15:55:00 |
+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Now I want the `difference` between two rows
Is it possible to get it
If I give this:

```
select (b.Sum(L2FramesSent) - a.Sum(L2FramesSent)),convert((min(a.datetime) div 500)*500, datetime) + INTERVAL 5 minute as endOfInterval from tablename.databasename a,tablename.databasename b where a.datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-12 11:00:00' AND '2012-09-12 17:05:00' group by a.datetime div 500;
```

I am getting error  `ERROR 1630 (42000): FUNCTION b.Sum does not exist`. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Both the tablename and databasename are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here:

```
select (b.Sum(L2FramesSent) - a.Sum(L2FramesSent))
```

try

```
select (Sum(b.L2FramesSent) - Sum(b.L2FramesSent))
```

instead

a and b are aliases for your table, and sum is an (generally available) function.

Comment: Thankyou,But i am getting ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION Sum.b does not exist,error

Comment: can you paste your whole statement?

Comment: select (Sum.b(L2FramesSent) - Sum.a(L2FramesSent)),convert((min(a.datetime) div 500)*500, datetime) + INTERVAL 5 minute as endOfInterval from 6panview.Statistics3 a,6panview.Statistics3 b where a.datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-12 11:00:00' AND '2012-09-12 17:05:00' group by a.datetime div 500;
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION Sum.b does not exist

Comment: look at my answer - not "sum.b(" -> "sum(b."

Comment: Thankyou,I have got something very huge values.What does the expression actually mean.

Comment: What i need is,I have got one table know,which contains Sum(L2FramesSent) of every 5minutess.I want the difference between each of two rows

Comment: sorry, i don't have time to solve this for your specific problem, but there is a solution for a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078987/calculate-deltadifference-of-current-and-previous-row-in-sql